# What he is saying is essentially true / truth

Tags: word-choice

> What he is saying is **essentially true**.

Can I replace here "true" {adjective} with "truth" {noun}? As I understand it, "true" in that sentence is like a noun. Does that replacement change the meaning?

Comment: I don't see how "true" in this sentence is "like a noun".  "What he is saying is true" is not structurally different from "The car is red."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace "true" with "truth" without changing the meaning.

I would be a little surprised to read that
sentence with "truth" instead of "true". Context might suggest that the writer was not a native speaker, or might make me pause to think a little. Somehow "truth" instead of "true" seems (to me) a very slightly more forceful claim.

Comment: One of the meanings of truth is a true statement. However, being a noun,  it would need the article. So what's wrong with "What he's saying is the truth (, essentially)"?

Comment: @VictorB.I agree that "the truth" is better, and more nearly synonymous with just plain "true". If I saw just plain "truth" I would wonder ... but not necessarily flag as a language error. (Caveat - I am not a grammarian.)